# Insert/Update/Delete of EF in Business layer

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I can't live with the idea that we need to recreate the insert/update/delete functionality in ALL pocos/bl objects? EF and linq2sql that have this so nice built in by itself.

How do you guys solve this on a effective way? Using a base class or some magic in the IQueryable pocos?

.NET 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Entity Framework / Linq objects are probably inherited from some base class you can inherit the objects in your business layer from a single base class. Then do something like this:

```
public class BusinessBaseCollection
{
    protected EFBaseCollection _efObject = null;

    public BusinessBaseCollection(EFBaseCollection efObject)
    {
        _efObject = efObject;
    }

    public Add(BusinessBase obj)
    {
        _efObject.Add(obj);
    }

    //Add other CRUD stuff here
}
```

Comment: I find that interesting. As you say. The methods are already there and I can't understand why we should redo them. Though, all my tries to make some kind of intelligence BL against EF is very unclear and slippery..

Comment: One very spooky effect is that I have to reference the DataLayer Assembly into the application, when trying such a base object (as you suggest above). Am i missing some fundamental here? Why can't business take that in mind itself..

Comment: Only normal that, if you use the EF Baseclass in some form you'll need to reference its assembly. No?

Comment: As for having to redo, that's layering for you. Each change needs to be done x times over. So much for DRY. With Entity Framework however you can take control more (using the T4) and perhaps derive from some central base class. All very "if and maybe" though...

Comment: Thank's. I can't se nothing else, but I'm not very happy with that. Why would I create a solution that talks to a business layer, if all the business layer tells me "Hi application X! I understand. I give you the paket, but you have to take this from DAL yourself, ok?". There have to be a work-around?

Comment: The theory is that the Business Objects CAN be very different from the DAL ones and/or perform high-level checks that really have no business (har har) in the DAL or are not feasable to implement there. But yeah, 99% of the time it's just passing stuff over.